# SSD not found - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I just replaced my SSD in a desktop (Asus Rampage III Formula MB).  The system has the SSD (with OS) and two HDD with data. If the HDD are plugged in, about 95% time, the SSD isn't found and I get an 'Error Loading OS' message.

I've tried setting the system to use IDE and AHCI. No difference. This was occuring with the first SSD, but much more with new one.  Old one was a Corsair F80 80GB. The new one a SanDisk Extreme II 240GB (it is also SATA 6GB).

Any ideas what is going on? Is there a setting I need to make, so the SSD is found reliably?

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like you dont have enough power

Comment: Can you see the drive in the bios/efi interface?

Comment: I have 900W power supply. No I can't see the drive in the BIOS interface (not sure what efi is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've determined that the issue was related to the Marvall PCIe 9128 controller. This is an addon conroller and apparently doesn't work well with the bootable drives. I plugged it into the primary intel 3GB ports and it works great. Which means I'm not running as fast as iI could, but a 3GB port is better than a brick.

Comment: Is your BIOS up to date? Latest one is [0903 from 2011/10/10](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/RAMPAGE_III_FORMULA/#support)

Comment: Yes, I loaded latest from Asus site...